# PHP Soap issue: OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54 or SSL: Connection reset by peer

Tags: php, ssl, curl, soap, wsdl

I try to execute SOAP request,

1. request works well on Soap UI gives proper response, - copy paste payload from tries bellow
2. request not work on Postman gives `Could not get any response` error
3. request not work using php SoapClient library giving `SoapClient::__doRequest(): SSL: Connection reset by peer` error
4. request not work using php curl gives `OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54` error

all ready tries SoapClient in no wsdl mode, and different ssl verification option, and tries on remote server so is not internet connection issue.

this is code for point 3:

```
$this->client = new \SoapClient($this->wsdl, [
            'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
            'exceptions' => true,
            'trace' => true,
            'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        ]);

$response = $this->client->__doRequest(trim($xml), $url, 'getReport', SOAP_1_1);
```

this is code for point 4:

```
 $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1); // both 0 & 1 not works
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $location);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY); // also tries different values
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15); // here too
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, trim($request));

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); // also not works without this
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); // and this

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

what can i do to debug this issue more deeply and solve it?

Comment: Do you control the server? Can you look at its logfiles? Otherwise did you try with another client to the same server, like `openssl s_client`? Or `curl` on the command line.

Comment: don't have access to server log allready tried on curl and soapclient, with no success, wonder why SoapUi works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out that header value `SOAPAction` needs to be in extra escaped quote like this:

```
$headers = [
   "SOAPAction: \"http://example-url.com\"",
]
```